# how to convert json string to php associative array without 0 => at top of each level

Tags: php, json

Hi to all I have those nested json data, at a very basic level they looks like this

```
$json = '{
      "destinazione": [
        {
          "corfu": [
            {
              "dataPartenza": [
                {
                  "18/11/83": [
                    {
                      "sistemazione": [
                        {
                          "comfort": [
                            [
                              {
                                "2pax-studio": "€6"
                              }
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }';
```

Now I want to send those datas to the php server for manipulation stuffs, and I'm using this code to show the data

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    print_r($jsonDecode);
```

And I'm Obtaining this:

```
Array
(
    [destinazione] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [corfu] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [dataPartenza] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [18/11/83] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [sistemazione] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                                (
                                                                                    [comfort] => Array
                                                                                        (
                                                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                                                (
                                                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                                                        (
                                                                                                            [2pax-studio] => €6
                                                                                                        )

                                                                                                )

                                                                                        )

                                                                                )

                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But I'm expecting something similar to this,

```
Array
(
[destinazione] => Array
    (
        [corfu] => Array
            (
                [dataPartenza] => Array
                    (
                        [18/11/83] => Array
                        (
                            [sistemazione] => Array
                            (
                                [comfort] => Array
                                (
                                    [2posti] => 6euro
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

so I was expecting an associative array without 0 => at top of each level,  maybe my json scheme is wrong and this is why I'm obtaining an unexpected result? I'm noob with php..
many thanks

Comment: If you don't want (non-associative) arrays in your JSON, you need to remove all the corresponding square brackets (`[` and `]`). Then the PHP representation won't have them either.

Comment: Instead of `"destinazione": [
        {` the `[ {` just use one or the other, both cause an extra level of nesting.

Comment: Your JSON contains arrays, so the decoded data contains arrays.

Comment: @AbraCadaver He can't use "one or the other". It has to be `{}` to get the named keys.

Comment: @Jeto performing string operations on serialized data is virtually _always_ an awful idea that will break down the line.

Comment: ok I understood, but my Json file is dinamycally generated through a big nested form, so the json scheme was looking good for me from the client side, it is nested through some each() loops that are using the indexes of the arreys for populating datas.

I think that is impossible to generate this without usingg [ ] from the client side, but in php it becomes somehow different. Maybe I have to find a different way to populate the data without using square brackets

Comment: @Sammitch I didn't mean to change the string data *after* it's generated/retrieved. I was merely responding to "maybe my json scheme is wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would want to solve this problem at the *source*, as in fixing the thing that's producing this weird format.

Failing that, if you need to perform operations on data structures of arbitrary depth that's a case for recursion.

```php
$data = json_decode($json, true);

function ensmallen($input) {
    if( is_array($input) ) {
        // if it's a numerically-indexed array with exactly one key
        if( array_keys($input) === [0] ) {
            return ensmallen($input[0]);
        } else {
            foreach($input as $key => $value) {
                $input[$key] = ensmallen($value);
            }
        }
    }
    return $input;
}

var_dump(ensmallen($data));
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["destinazione"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["corfu"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["dataPartenza"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["18/11/83"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["sistemazione"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["comfort"]=>
            array(1) {
              ["2pax-studio"]=>
              string(4) "€6"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Beware, though. If any of those indexed arrays ever have more than one entry, eg: more than one destination, this is going to break all the code that comes after it. Since it will be `$foo[1]['destinazione']` instead of `$foo['destinazione']`.

Once again, solving the problem at the *source* of the data would be the best course of action. The second-best being using the data as-is, and the code I've just posted being a distant third.

Comment: thank you this is really clear, I will find a fix at the source stage but this openend my mynd.thanks